# Installing moodle on Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: server, moodle

I am following the guide on [Installation guide used](https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Step-by-step_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu#Step_3:_Install_Additional_Software) how to install moodle but im getting stuck on step 5 on command `sudo cp -R /opt/moodle /var/www/html/` after executing the command i receive  error messages that state that i am unable to create the directories due to insufficient space. Even though i have over 30gb disk space allocated to the Linux server

Answer (score 0):

1. Was less space allocated to your server before?
2. What does `df -h` show?
3. If 1. is true, run `sudo resize2fs /dev/<insert your root partition here>` and reboot

Comment: 1. The server had 30gb allocated from creation.   2. output of df -h [image link](https://imgur.com/a/wRYdsXa)

Comment: Seems like your root partition has the size of 3.9gb only.

What does `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` print?

Try `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`.

Comment: [output of lsblk] (https://imgur.com/a/7VZCVkF)

Comment: Looks good. `resize2fs` should work then.

Comment: tried the `resize2fs` command you provided above still the same error

Comment: Did `resize2fs` output something like nothing to do or expanded it your disk? Have you rebooted already if it did something?

Comment: yes the output stated nothing to do and i rebooted after executing the `resize2fs` command

Comment: okay, your partition needs to be resized too. The following command should resize your partition and your filesystem: `lvextend --resizefs --size +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`
Edit: better use --size instead of -l

Comment: sorry, not `--size`, `--extents` should be the way to go:
`sudo lvextend --resizefs --extents +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for this issue. You can use fixed size drives to avoid this issue instead of dynamically sized drives